# Issues with Nginx returning 302/307 instead of 200/500

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx to load balance / Reverse proxy a website.

Setup is 1 Machine for load balancing 
 + 3 Machines to host the web content.

Site configuration is as follows :

```
  upstream api_app {
    least_conn;
    server sfront1.mydomain.org:5000;
    server sfront2.mydomain.org:5000;
    server sfront3.mydomain.org:5000;


  }
   server {
    listen        80;
    listen        [::]:80;
    server_name   mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://api_app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /images {
        alias /home/images/mangas;
        try_files $uri /404Cover.jpg;
   }
    location /Images {
        alias /home/images/mangas;
        try_files $uri /404Cover.jpg;
   }
   location /Covers {
        alias /home/images/light-novels;
        try_files $uri /404Cover.jpg;
   }
  }

  server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
  }
```

Now I checked the logs of the clients of that API and they randomly receive 302/307 Http Responses.

Now I'm pretty positive the backend did not send those. So it's probably Nginx.

Any idea what those responses could be? Why it seems completely random ?

Both nginx/backends only work in Http. Not https.

Could this have anything to do with the 2 lines I don't quite get in the configuration :

```
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Comment: The nginx configuration you have shown does not contain any redirects. The two lines you call out are for passing through WebSockets. You should actually check your web application to find the redirects.

Comment: You need to check your full config /etc/nginx.conf and all includes for redirects, or it makes your app.